# Symfony Forms - Getting multiple unmapped collections to merge and submit to a single entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, sylius

I have a WholesaleRuleset entity
(https://pastebin.com/PYjHmGi1)
With a M2M relationship to WholesaleRuleQuantityStep (https://pastebin.com/JLrQfQV7).

This relationship is properly set up. It works *perfectly* in WholesaleRulesetType (https://pastebin.com/VGCdABb9).[This is the "Edit" page of the submitted ruleset with its quantity step rule collection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k879O.png)

Here's where my requirements get tricky. As you can see, the admin can add quantitySteps at the scopes Taxonomy, Product, and Taxonomy *using different tabs*.

I am trying to have multiple, separate collections submit to the same entity.:

- QuantityStepRuleByTaxonomy
- QuantityStepRuleByProduct
- QuantityStepRuleByProductVariant

WholesaleRulesetType would end up looking like this (even added the necessary collection methods in this trait https://pastebin.com/F5B97xgW).
Desired form type:

```
            ->add(
                'quantityStepRulesByTaxon',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByTaxonType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'quantityStepRulesByProduct',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByProductType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'quantityStepRulesByProductVariant',
                CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByProductVariantType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                ]
            );
```

And in the request data they all combine to submit to WholesaleRuleQuantityStep. It must be separate collections, because you cannot use the same form field more than once simultaneously.
I have been stuck on this for a month. No responses from the Sylius or Symfony slacks. Please. Help.

Comment: Okay, just checking if I understand correctly: You have *one* many-to-many relation, and in your form you partition the entities in the collection into three sub-collections to edit them on different tabs/pages?

Comment: Almost exactly that. I want to partition the single entity WholesaleRuleQuantityStep into three collections with different "entry_types": (WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByTaxonType, WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByProductType, WholesaleRuleQuantityStepByProductVariantType) then merge them with a form event so they all submit to the same object/entity - WholesaleRuleQuantityStep.
This entity actually has a m2m relation with entities taxon, product, and productVariant. These were also set up correctly.

I tried using data mappers etc. but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Okay, I hope I do get this right now, for brevity (and lazyness) I have shortened all class names and field names, because your MWE is quite extensive and unnecessarily verbose. So, you have to map my entity RuleSet to your WholesaleRuleset and my Rule to your WholesaleRuleQuantityStep.)

I believe you have two entities RuleSet and Rule, connected via many-to-many. The rules have essentially three types product, variant and taxon.

Now you want to display those rules in different form fields, which you try to mitigate by essentially creating new properties on your object via your trait, but as far as I can tell, those are not connected at all to the many-to-many field.

To be able to edit your entity later as well, I propose the following: Make your "fields" fully virtual. For Symfony forms a "field" is actually something that a property accessor can access for reading and writing (getting and setting, or getting and adding and removing in the case of collections).

I have done this a couple of times and I love the concept, for each of your types of rules do this:

```php
// in class RuleSet
protected $rules; // <-- collection containing *all* rules.

public function getTaxonRules(): array {
    // extract the rules of type taxon
    return array_filter(function($rule) {
        return $rule->getType() == 'taxon';
    }, $this->rules->toArray());
}
public function addTaxonRule(Rule $rule) {
    // you might even set the type here ;o)
    if (!in_array($rule, $this->getTaxonRules()) && $rule->getType() == 'taxon') {
        $this->rules->add($rule);
    }
}
public function removeTaxonRule(Rule $rule) {
    if (in_array($rule, $this->getTaxonRules()) && $rule->getType() == 'taxon') {
        $this->rules->removeElement($rule);
    }
}
// add these functions:
// public function getVariantRules() ...
// public function addVariantRule(Rule $rule) ...
// public function removeVariantRule(Rule $rule) ...
// public function getProductRules() ...
// public function addProductRule(Rule $rule) ...
// public function removeProductRule(Rule $rule) ...
```

This way, the entity acts as if it has a field `taxonRules`, because what really is a field if not its interface to the outside world (which is getters and setters). The outside doesn't care about the implementation details inside.

Note: the tests for `$rule->getType() == ...` really shouldn't be necessary. Also, no form events or other fancy stuff should be required, you can now just go ahead and have three form fields.

Side-Note: I really don't like exposing `Collection`s to the outside of my entity. Any changes to the collection is supposed to be happening via setters/adders/removers. returning an array will also make `byReference => false` obsolete. In my opinion having collections isn't worth the trouble in this case. You might be able to make it work, but the amount of code will be bigger (with nothing gained, imho).

(Side-Burn: yoda conditions are out! Also: try adding a function to your Rule `isTaxonRule(): bool`, don't use "magic" strings in your code, they don't support auto-completion, at least use constants on your Rule class, where these strings are stored and go like `$rule->getType() === Rule::TAXON`, however, don't use strings directly. a typo can mess up your code and you might only notice in production ;o))

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I tried something similar before having the external collection simply call the main one's adder, and after having tried both what ends up happening is the ruleset successfully submits without the rule.

Here's my [new trait](https://pastebin.com/eeypsAjY) trying to map your example. Perhaps I missed a step in your answer?

Maybe I just need to decorate Sylius' [Resource Controller](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/src/Bundle/Controller/ResourceController.php) and do the doctrine things manually?

Comment: Ah. I had to call $rule->setRuleset($this) in BOTH adders for some reason. I'll look into it, but it works. Now it's simply a matter of making some validations to ensure a rule object exists within the ruleset upon submission.

I'll take your other suggestions to heart and do quite a bit of refactoring especially for verbosity. Wish I had a senior like you in my first job. Thanks. You've really removed a huge slump.

Comment: you're welcome. yeah, a senior is a huge benefit when it comes to removing blockers ;o) also *anyone* to bounce ideas off of is very good. both of which I have experienced and benefitted from a bunch.